# HashMap/TreeMap sorting my keys

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, treemap

Using JSoup I am scraping some data from a website that gives me pollen data. They do not have an API access, so scraping was my last resort.

Using a `HashMap`, I am storing the `date` and the `pollenIndex`, which is how high pollen levels are that day on a scale of 0.0 - 10.0.

```
private static Map<String, String> pollenMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

This is part of the constructor of my `Pollen` class.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Element dates = doc.select("td.text-center.even-four").get(i);
    Element levels = doc.select("td.levels").get(i);

    System.out.println(dates.text() + ", " + levels.text());

    pollenMap.put(dates.text(), levels.text());
}
```

One issue is that `HashMap` sorts the data for me. The output of the `pollenMap` is this:

```
 : [Monday May 26, 2014, Wednesday May 28, 2014, Sunday May 25, 2014, Tuesday May 27, 2014]
 : [7.90, 6.60, 7.60, 8.80]
```

As you can see, `HashMap` sorts my `dates` keys, resulting in `Monday` coming first, and `Tuesday` last.

I may be using the `HashMap` incorrectly, so my friend suggested I use `TreeMap`, however, the result of that was this:

```
 : [Monday May 26, 2014, Wednesday May 28, 2014, Sunday May 25, 2014, Tuesday May 27, 2014]
 : [7.90, 6.60, 7.60, 8.80]
```

How do I use this key-value structure without it being sorted?

Apologies for the novice question on this data structure. I could use two `String` lists but I want to learn these new data structures.

Comment: Oh, I apologize. Does this mean I am using `HashMap` incorrectly?

Comment: Is it a problem that the order is changed? Or does it just surprise you? Often, when you want a key-value mapping, order of the key-value pairs doesn't matter.

Comment: The order of iteration over a `TreeMap` depends on the type of the objects used as keys. You can also provide a custom `Comparator` to affect the order. My guess is that your trouble stems from the format of the strings you're using as keys and the lack of a sensible function capable of comparing them the way you want. You'd be better off parsing the strings as dates and using the dates as keys instead.

Comment: It is worth reading Java doc and checking basic information about the data structures being used first, prior to asking such a trivial question. -1

Comment: @OlegS. In my opinion it was less about the data structure but the wrong data type to use as inputs. I used `String`, but the correct way would have been `Date`. I am now using `Date` instead of `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) `java.util.HashMap` makes no guarantees about order.

(2) `java.util.SortedMap`, such as `java.util.TreeMap` sorts by key. (In your case, sorting the `String` keys lexicographically.)

---

> How do I use this key-value structure without it being sorted?

If you want to iterate over the key-values in the order in which you inserted them, you need [`java.util.LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

> This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

---

> OP doesn't want to preserve insertion order. He/she wants date order.

If you want to iterate over the key-values in the order of the dates, use a `java.util.TreeMap`, but [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) the `String`s to `Date`s.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE MMMM d, yyyy");
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Element dates = doc.select("td.text-center.even-four").get(i);
    Element levels = doc.select("td.levels").get(i);

    System.out.println(dates.text() + ", " + levels.text());

    pollenMap.put(format.parse(dates.text()), levels.text());
}
```

Incidentally, you may want to do the same for your measurements, and store them as `long`s or `java.math.BigDecimal`s.

Comment: +1 for LinkedHashMap.  It's the right answer to this question "as asked", even though I think it's not what OP wants.

Comment: Hi Paul. I have implemented my own SimpleDateFormat parser. I did not use yours, but it ended up looking the same anyways as what we were trying to achieve was the same. My question is, my date parser adds in `HH:mm:ss` by itself as well, such as this: `Sun May 25 00:00:00 EDT 2014`. Why is it doing this?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage, a `Date` in Java is actually a date *and time*. By default, when you call [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()) on it, the time is included. If you don't want the time in the `String` representation, you can use the same `DateFormat`, and do [`format.format(myDate)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)). (FYI, if you happen to dislike Java 7's date APIs, you might enjoy some of improvements coming with Java 8.)

Comment: Would what you explained only be done on the `get` process? As you said, adding the `Date` object is actually a date and time.

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap` does not sort the data; it hashes the keys to assign the data to buckets! You can create a Key-Value type and store your data in a `List` or a `Stack`. They will preserve your insertion order.

Comment: @PaulDraper TreeMap does sort the keys. OP wants to preserve insertion order. *How do I use this key-value structure without it being sorted?*

Comment: No, OP doesn't want to preserve insertion order.  He/she wants date order.

Comment: Thanks David, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using `String` values to store both dates, and decimals.  When you sort, your dates are getting sorted alphabetically, which in this case is putting Monday before Saturday, and so on.

Since you're storing date data and decimal data in your map, you should make it a `TreeMap<Date,BigDecimal>` instead of a `TreeMap<String,String>`.  Parse your dates and your decimals before putting them into the map.  The `TreeMap` code will then sort them correctly.

Comment: OP: "How do I use this key-value structure without it being sorted?" I misread the same as you at first.

Comment: No, @PaulDraper, he/she meant not to re-order the dates alphabetically.  I don't believe I have misunderstood this.  But perhaps OP can clarify.

Comment: From the OP's comments on Elliott's answer it does instead appear that date order is what is wanted instead of "without it being sorted". Great mind reading :P